# Иерархия консольного меню

Tags: c#, ооп, консоль, меню

Может кто знает как правильно организовывать вызовы меню в логике консольного приложения?
Допустим есть класс логики.И много классов меню.
Как в этой логике их вызывать в одном методе слишком много получается кода. В разных методах, но эти методы вызывают друг друга, что будет неправильно?

Если есть спецы по тестированию, подскажите как можно тестировать методы которые вызывают другие методы, или отрефакторить код разорвав эти связи?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование ООП подхода в консольном приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805028/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: @tym32167 Причина закрытия как дубликат "этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение", но вопрос по ссылке ещё не имеет решения. Вопрос к ТС: Почему вы задаёте почти один и тот же  вопрос повторно?

Comment: Это другой вопрос

Comment: Хмм, может вы и правы, но уже как минимум два участника особой разницы не заметили. И не по сути вопроса - добавляйте в комментариях [@имя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6939/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0/6940?s=5|19.0863#6940)

Comment: я запутался, что за имя? @0xdb

Comment: так вы и сами так не делаете @0xdb

Comment: там вопрос для метки `инспекция кода` - здесь обычный вопрос. Другое дело насколько от подходит для формата SO.

Comment: Определите формат SO, пожалуйста @Foggy Finde

Comment: я не могу и не должен - для этих целей есть сообщество и модераторы ;-) Захотят - закроют. Но я бы оставил открытым.

Comment: Ну вот именно!! вы же часть сообщества, давайте ограничьте формат вопросов  @Foggy Finde

Comment: @0xdb на самом деле я получил оповещение. Можно и просто <знак собачки>Foggy все равно сработает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как и в предыдущем вопросе, так и в этом, я бы выбрал чтото вроде машины состояний. 
Например, определим интерфейс состояния

```
public interface IState
{
    IState RunState();
}
```

что такое по сути состояние с меню? Для начала меню

```
public class MenuItem
{   
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

Далее состояние, где есть пункты меню и где юзер может эти пункты выбрать. Например, простой базовый класс:

```
public abstract class MenuState : IState
{
    protected abstract Dictionary<int, MenuItem> Menus { get; }

    protected virtual void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have options:");
        foreach (var m in Menus)
            Console.WriteLine($"{m.Key} - {m.Value.Text}");
    }

    protected virtual KeyValuePair<int, MenuItem> ReadOption()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, select option:");
        ShowMenu();

        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        int answerId = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(str, out answerId))
        {
            if (!Menus.ContainsKey(answerId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Selected item notexists.");
                return ReadOption();
            }
            return new KeyValuePair<int, MenuItem>(answerId, Menus[answerId]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Selected item not a number.");
            return ReadOption();
        }
    }

    public virtual IState RunState()
    {
        var option = ReadOption();
        return NextState(option);
    }

    protected abstract IState NextState(KeyValuePair<int, MenuItem> selectedMenu);
}
```

Как пример простого состояния с несколькими пунктами

```
public class MenuState1 : MenuState
{
    private Dictionary<int, MenuItem> _menus = new Dictionary<int, MenuItem>() {
        {1, new MenuItem(){Text = "Menu 1"}},
        {2, new MenuItem(){Text = "Menu 2"}},
        {3, new MenuItem(){Text = "Menu 3"}},
        {4, new MenuItem(){Text = "Exit"}},
    };
    protected override Dictionary<int, MenuItem> Menus => _menus;

    protected override IState NextState(KeyValuePair<int, MenuItem> selectedMenu)
    {
        if (selectedMenu.Key == 4) return null;
        if (selectedMenu.Key == 1) return new AuthState();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Ну, или вот состояние без меню

```
public class AuthState : IState
{   
    public IState RunState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login: ");
        var login = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Password: ");
        var password = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {login}");

        return new MenuState1();
    }
}
```

Как это все использовать:

```
IState startState = new AuthState();    
while(startState!=null) startState = startState.RunState();
```

Как пример вывода

```
Login: 
Password: 
Hello, Vasya
Please, select option:
You have options:
1 - Menu 1
2 - Menu 2
3 - Menu 3
4 - Exit
```

Из плюсов - каждое состояние знает только о следующем состоянии, и даже это можно делегировать стороннему классу.

Ну, или можно сделать состояние настраиваемым, например

```
public class ConfigurableMenuState : MenuState
{
    private Dictionary<int, MenuItem> _menus = new Dictionary<int, MenuItem>();
    private Dictionary<int, Func<IState>> _transitions = new Dictionary<int, Func<IState>>();

    protected override Dictionary<int, MenuItem> Menus => _menus;   

    protected override IState NextState(KeyValuePair<int, MenuItem> selectedMenu)
    {   
        return _transitions[selectedMenu.Key]();
    }

    public void AddMenuItem(int id, MenuItem menu, Func<IState> nextState)
    {
        _menus.Add(id, menu);
        _transitions.Add(id, nextState);
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var menuState = new ConfigurableMenuState();
menuState.AddMenuItem(1, new MenuItem() {Text = "Option 1"}, ()=> menuState);
menuState.AddMenuItem(2, new MenuItem() {Text = "Exit"}, ()=> null);

IState startState = menuState;  
while(startState!=null) startState = startState.RunState();
```

Вывод

```
Please, select option:
You have options:
1 - Option 1
2 - Exit
```

Из преимуществ - класс автономный, зависимостей нет, тестируй не хочу.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!!!