# Switch конструкция

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть конструкция `switch` в которой я выбираю задачи, главная цель проекта заполнить анкету, еще в этом же `switch` я хочу сделать команды перейти к предыдущему или следующему вопросу, очистить анкету, и что бы к этим командам можно было обращаться из метода `_formFormService.Initialization();` как я могу это реализовать? что бы во время заполнения анкеты можно было юзать каманды??

```
public void GetInterface()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter command...");
            var inputCommand = Console.ReadLine();
            String[] commandParts = null;

            if (inputCommand != null)
                commandParts = inputCommand.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            switch (commandParts[0])
            {
                case "-new_profile":
                    _formFormService.Initialization();
                    break;

                case "-save":
                    _formFormService.Save();
                    break;

                case "-delete":
                    _formFormService.Delete(commandParts[1] + ".txt");
                    break;

                case "-list":
                    _formsInformationService.GetTitles(DateTime.MinValue);
                    break;

                case "-list_today":
                    _formsInformationService.GetTitles(DateTime.UtcNow);
                    break;

                case "-find":
                    _formFormService.Details(commandParts[1] + ".txt");
                    break;

                case "-zip":
                    _formsInformationService.Compress(commandParts[1], commandParts[2]);
                    break;

                case "-help":
                    GetHelp();
                    break;

                case "-exit":
                    Console.WriteLine("pewPewpewPEWpeWpewPEWpEwPeWPEwpEW bye....");
                    return;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Заполнение анкеты

```
public void Initialization()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Full Name:");
        _formModel.FullName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth");
        _formModel.DateOfBirth = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your favourite language");
        _formModel.ProgrammingLanguage = (ProgrammingLanguages)Convert.ToConsole.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your experience");
        _formModel.Experience = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number");
        _formModel.Phone = Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Я как то писал [консольное меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805109/179763), поглядите, может и вам подойдет.

Comment: Я бы какой-нибудь словарь завел, где ключем является консольный ключ, а значение делегат.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит "во время заполнения анкеты можно было юзать команды". Если вы работаете в консоли и перешли в режим редактирования, не важно чего, нужно сначала завершить редактирование и тут могут быть различные варианты, от ожидания ввода последней необходимой строки, до ручного посимвольного ввода данных с отслеживанием управляющих наборов символов.