# Проектирование телеграм-бота

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net, шаблоны-проектирования

Я C#-бекэндер, соответственно, работаю на ASP.NET. Хочу создать некоторое гибкое решение для быстрой сборки телеграм-ботов, но не не могу придумать модель. В случае с ASP.NET очень хорошо смотрите MVC-паттерн, на основе которого и пишутся приложения, мне нужно какое-то похожее решение для телеграм-бота. В отличие от веб-морды, в телеграме необходимо сохранять историю переходов между контроллерами (по типу файлового каталога), соответственно, у каждого диалога должен быть свой текст, свой набор кнопок и свой обработчик нажатий на эти кнопки. Раньше я писал ботов так: у каждого пользователя есть поле - название диалога (контроллера), в котором он сейчас находится и при переключении диалогов вручную изменял название этого поля, а также выводил текст с кнопками. Соответственно, каждый контроллер состоял из огромного switch-case'а с кучей костылей и огромным количеством копипасты. Сейчас мне нужно что-то более подходящее

Comment: Да по тому же MVC паттерну и можете собрать, тем более он вам знаком. Разницы логически никакой, что будет в качестве UI - веб или мессенджер.

Comment: А вообще бот - это машина состояний, паттерн "конечный автомат". Проще некуда.

Comment: Да, это действительно логичное решение, но меня смущает, что все состояния будут лежать в одном пространстве и представлять из себя просто кучу классов одинакового уровня. Никакой иерархии. По-хорошему для построения такого автомата нужно написать еще и специальный конструктор таких состояний

Comment: так вам никто не запрещает любые графы между этими состояниями строить. Иерархия это дерево, а дерево - частный случай графа. А переходы между состояниями - это как раз тот самый граф. То есть логически у вас больше возможностей, чем у просто дерева. Поиграйтесь с графами, вдруг какие интересные мысли будут по организации переходов. А то что конечный автомат логичный - это как бы безальтернативное решение, просто любое другое будет либо менее гибкое, либо хуже масштабируемое. Я там ответ ниже нарисовал, если что. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет паттерн "конечный автомат", или его еще называют "машина состояний".

Покажу самый простой пример.

Вот код.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Реализую его с помощью конечного автомата вот такого типа:

```
public interface IStateMachine<T>
{
    T State { get; }

    bool MoveNext();
}
```

Реализация простая

```
public class CounterMachine : IStateMachine<int>
{
    private int _threshold;
    public int State { get; private set; }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (State == _threshold)
            return false;
        State++;
        return true;
    }

    public CounterMachine(int initialState, int endState)
    {
        State = initialState;
        _threshold = endState - 1;
    }
}
```

Тогда код, который будет делать то же самое, что и цикл `for`, будет выглядеть вот так:

```
var machine = new CounterMachine(0, 10);
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(machine.State);
} while (machine.MoveNext());
```

Смысл самого конечного автомата заключается в том, что он после выполнения каждого действия возвращает управление в вызывающий код. То есть:

1. вызвали
2. посмотрели состояние
3. поделали другие дела
4. переход к п.1

Экземпляр машины может быть создан для каждого подключения пользователя, следовательно каждый пользователь будет иметь свое собственное уникальное состояние этой машины.

Вы можете добавить переходы между состояниями (transition), выше показанный пример имеет только один переход, а вообще переход можно передавать аргументом в `MoveNext(transition)`, переход может выбираться например через пункт меню вашего бота или введенную команду. Можете посмотреть паттерн "команда", он очень популярен среди разработчиков WPF. Добавить метод машины "получить команды", который будет возвращать список команд только для текущего состояния машины.

Таким образом вы сможете избежать дублирования кода и реализовывать достаточно сложные машины без особых усилий.

В .NET паттерн "конечный автомат" широко используется, самый популярный - паттерн "итератор" `IEnumerable`: вам же знаком `yield return`? Вот это оно и есть. Кстати, можете реализовать свою машину на базе того же "итератора". И не менее популярная область применения того же автомата - `async`/`await`.

Comment: чет напомнило https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805109/179763