# Структура Телеграм бота C#

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Всем привет. Спасибо что зашли!:)
Пишу бота на C# одна из его задач это сбор данных о человеке, таких как время рождения, город, имя и прочее.
Я взял стандартную update функцию предложенную разработчиками библиотеки TelegramBotApi, которая вызывается при получении текстового сообщения и обрабатывает его в зависимости от содержания, но по мере разработки бота она становится весьма увесистой и очень хрупкой, потому что очень много проверок if.
Как мне более грамотно организовать функцию Update?
Желательно, чтобы если клиент находится в другом подразделе чата, где не требуется ввод информации о себе, но происходит взаимодействие с custom keyboards, чтобы не проходило лишних проверок на дату и время. Сейчас у меня стоят bool переменные, и, когда клиент вводит нужную информацию, то она меняется на true и уходит в БД, а функция Update может зайти в следующий if и запросить другие данные.
Я это вижу примерно так. Если клиент в подразделе где нужно вводить информацию о себе, то работает одна функция Update, если он в подразделе где взаимодействие осуществляется через custom keyboard, то другая, если в третьем, то третья.
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```
private static async Task BotOnMessageReceived(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Message message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Receive message type: {message.Type}");

    if (message.Text is not { } messageText)
        return;

    if (message.Text == "...")
    {
        ...
    }
        if (message.Text == "...")
    {
        ...
    }
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(message.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tob) && isDobSet)
    {
       ...
    }
    if(isTobSet&&isDobSet&&!isCitySet)
    {
       ...
    }
    if(isTobSet&&isDobSet&&isCitySet)
    {
       ...
    }


    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(message.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dob)&& !isDobSet)
    {
       ...
    }
    Message sentMessage = await action;
    Console.WriteLine($"The message was sent with id: {sentMessage.MessageId}");


}
```

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий как мне кажется. Нужно понимать что Вам нужно обрабатывать не только входящие сообщения, но и CallbackQuery и InlineQuery(если бот поддерживает inline-режим). Как принято на C# я не знаю, но на Java/python при написании ботов идут в сторону StateMachine и Handler'ов для обработки конкретных эвентов... это то, что я могу вкратце рассказать. Если кто-то на C# разрабатывает ботов - может поделиться более конкретным опытом

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373561/373567) Плюс разбивайте большие методы на много маленьких, давайте им понятные имена, [используйте ООП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375879/373567).

Comment: Вот еще [ответ в тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805109/373567).

Comment: Благодарю, ребят за ответы. Да, используются разные handlers, inline  тоже используется. Значит буду организовывать state machine.