# Cценарии диалога Telegram Bot

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, telegram, callback

Всех приветствую!

Чтобы получить `CallBack` в `telegram bot` можно использовать такой способ:

```
 var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                // first row
                new []
                {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.1", "11"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("1.2", "12"),
                },
                // second row
                new []
                {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.1", "21"),
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("2.2", "22"),
                }
            });

            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Нажмите на кнопку:", replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard);
```

А потом получать `CallBack` так:

```
await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    callbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
    $"Received {callbackQuery.Data}"
);
```

Но, перерыл все и никак не могу понять, как я могу сделать перехват `CallBack` с сообщений, а не `inline` кнопок.

Идея в создании стандартного меню с `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` и в определенный момент от пользователя потребуется реализовать сценарий: ввести 1 `string` из английских букв(либо отменить действие при помощи кнопки) затем к нему поступит инструкция, что нужно ввести уже другое, затем ввести еще 1 сообщение `decimal`(опять же с возможностью вернуться к началу в главное меню).

Но, я не понимаю, как реализовать ожидание ввода пользователем определенной строки, чтобы задать после ее ввода следующий вопрос.
Предполагаю, что это делается по аналогии с `inline` кнопками, только сообщения пользователя кидают `CallBack`, а я должен его ловить, но никаких примеров в документации и интернете не нашел на `C#` именно.

Comment: Этот вопрос интересует меня, если вы нашли ответ, пожалуйста ответьте сюда

Comment: @ВикторДробышев https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373561/373567, вот ещё по теме почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382349/373567