# Как в консольном приложении вернуться на шаг обратно?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь написать консольное меню на C#.

вот отрывок от кода:

```
static void MainWindow()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Hauptmenü");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Information");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Kontakt");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Extra");
    Console.WriteLine("q. Beenden");
    string myOptions;
    myOptions = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (myOptions)
    {
        case "1":
            Information();
            break;
        case "2":
            Kontakt();
            break;
        case "3":
            Extra();
            break;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Information()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("a) Unternehmen");
    Console.WriteLine("b) Entwicklung");
    Console.WriteLine("c) Verwaltung");
    Console.WriteLine("q) Zurück");
    string val1 = Console.ReadLine();
    while(true)
    {
        if(val1 == "a")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("ALLINSIGHT IT-Services GmbH ist eine Irrenanstalt");
            break;
        } 
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы после появление данного сообщения:

> "Console.WriteLine("ALLINSIGHT IT-Services GmbH ist eine Irrenanstalt");"

я мог при нажатии на любую клавишу клавиатуры просто вернуться на шаг обратно?

**UPD:** Скаэите как мне создать счетчик который будет считать не правильные вводы пользователя и когда достигает 5 то выкидывает в главное меню

Comment: шаг обратно это куда? что должно произойти?

Comment: В главное меню, пример мой это уже когдапользоватль нажал на Инфомацию что бы я обратно вернулся в MainWindow

Comment: такое делается через бесконечный цикл. Тут много вопросов на эту тему, поищите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805109/220553

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375879/373567

Comment: вот попроще пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1171427/373567

Comment: Получилось. А вопрос такой не могу разобраться, как создаать счестчик который бдует считать не правильные вводы пользователя, и когда счестик будет равен 5 его выкидывало из консоли ?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { код; }`